# Best way to read content of website after login

Tags: html

So there is a contest going on where you can win tickets for a local festival. They display the number of tickets available, but you can only access that page after a login. I was making a java program to read the HTML content but can´t find a way to login first a then read the content.

So heres where I need help, what is the best way to have a script/program request a refresh on said page every once in a while, in order for me to read the content and do some kind of statistics on the way the tickets are sorted.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Did you google it to begin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to achieve the solution. Actually it is the related testing part of Java. You can look into **Selenium web driver**. It will take a while to setup. But once it done, you just need to change parameters like website url and username and password, and you will be able to login in any website and render the 
HTML content. I learned from [here](http://www.guru99.com/introduction-webdriver-comparison-selenium-rc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found out the best/simple way, if you want to store just simple data is creating a script with greasemonkey and store the data using cookies